# Get and Set different data types in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, objectmapper

I am using ObjectMapper. And I know we can specify the keypath like map["name.label"] but I don't want to use keyPath at a moment. Check the below code. I can access name like `Author.name?.label`.

```
class Author: Mappable {
    var name: LabelDict? 

    required init?(map: Map) {
    }        

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name <- map["name"]
    }
}

class LabelDict: Mappable {
    var label: String?

    required init?(map: Map) {
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        label <- map["label"]
    }
}
```

How can I set the getter and setter methods of the name property of Author class to set the value as `LabelDict` class label and when I get the value I get the `String` directly as `Author.name`. I can do it by using one different variable but is it possible to do with the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your `LabelDict` adopt `CustomStringConvertible` protocol.

```
class LabelDict: Mappable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var label: String?
    var description: String {
        get {
            return self.label ?? ""
        }
    }

    required init?(map: Map) {
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        label <- map["label"]
    }
}
```

Then you'd use it like this `String(describing: myLabelDictInstance)`.

-- Clarification
To simply print the `label` into console you can now use `print(Author?.name)`. If you want to assign it to label for example, you can use `someLabel.text = String(describing: Author?.name)`

Comment: I don't get how to use String(describing: myLabelDictInstance).

Comment: I Fetch value like this print(Author?.name?.label)